# Convert an unknown data item to string in Python

Tags: python-3.x, string

I have certain data that need to be converted to strings. Example:

> [ABCGHDEF-12345, ABCDKJEF-123235,...]

The example above does not represent a constant or a string by itself but is taken from an Excel sheet (ranging upto 30+ items for each row). I want to convert these to strings. Since data is undefined, explicitly converting them doesn't work. Is there a way to do this iteratively without placing double/single quotes manually between each data element?

What I want finally:

> ["ABCGHDEF-12345", "ABCDKJEF-123235",...]

Comment: So whats the question? Do you want to convert the string `[ABCGHDEF-12345, ABCDKJEF-123235]` to a list of strings `["ABCGHDEF-12345", "ABCDKJEF-123235"]` ?

Comment: @AndrejKesely, yes you're right, I edited my question above, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert the string to list of strings you can try:

```py
s = "[ABCGHDEF-12345, ABCDKJEF-123235]"

s = s.strip("[]").split(", ")
print(s)
```

Prints:

```
['ABCGHDEF-12345', 'ABCDKJEF-123235']
```